# How do I update an individual package without breaking future updates?

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, libraries

I'm on a LTS release and want it to remain LTS.  However, I have an individual package called libmlx4-1 that I need to update to version 1.04 (i.e. [libmlx4-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/quantal/libmlx4)) .  This is in the Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) release but not 12.04 (precise) yet and I need that.

How can I obtain this individual package from 12.04 (which already has it's dependencies met on 12.04) and install it without breaking future updates?

Comment: Have you tried to install the Quantal version? maybe the dependencies in 12.04 are enough for it.

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  I don't want to move away from a LTS release.  I just want to obtain the quantel deb file for libmlx4-1.  Where do I get it from without installing the entire OS? I can obtain the source package but I don't want to go to the trouble of building it from source.

Comment: From your link, click the package, then select your architecture and download it.

Comment: But, those are source packages...

Comment: Those are deb packages download them and install them. They don't contain any source code.

Comment: Ok, It wasn't clear what link was the actual download for the package.  What confused me were the words "Download libmlx4-1" at the bottom of that page.  Instead I should have clicked the link at the top directly after the words "The following binary packages are built from this source package:".

Comment: But does it work for you? does it install correctly?

Comment: Yes it works correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/quantal/libmlx4) you added to your question:

- Click on the package you want to download `libxml4-1`.

[image]

- Then choose your architecture.

[image]

Then choose a mirror and download it.

And just as that the site advises you:

> If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

You can install them and if the dependencies in your version are enough to satisfy the package it will install but you won't get automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

To update the package you need and all it's dependencies package try.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml4-1
```

or

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install libxml4-1
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It installs the latest release for 12.04, not from 12.10.  I have updated my question with more specific detail.